# setting username and password in the http header for a SOAP request message using zeep (python)?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, passwords, zeep

How can you set the username and password in the http header for a SOAP request message using python's zeep? I believe that is why i am getting a connection refused error but cannot figure out where the http header details can be set. I even tried just running python -mzeep on the wsdl file (vs creating a client and calling a web service method) but it still cannot connect.

Answer (score 8):

Zeep uses the requests library for http requests. The request session is available as `client.transport.session`.

So doing something like `client.transport.session.headers.update({})` should work. See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Answer (score 2):

this one works just fine

```
client.transport.session.headers.update({'yourHeader': 'yourValue'})
```